# Duvidas na instalação php7.0 no Debian 8

Tags: php, servidor, xampp, linux

Ae galera
Estou instalando php7 no servidor linux, debian8 e queria saber onde eu consigo a listagem de todos os pacotes do php que existem, conheço alguns mas queria saber se tem onde eu ver todos os que são usados por exemplo em uma instalação xampp do windows. Para eu saber o quee u preciso instalar no servidor linux.

Desde ja agradeço :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você de deve saber quais pacotes você ira utilizar, Não instale pacotes desnecessários. Mas caso você queira, você pode digitar: "apt-get install php" e pressionar a tecla tab duas vezes o próprio terminal ira listar as instalações do PHP pra você.